# Black and white balls in 2 boxes probability

Tags: probability

I have an exercise which is confusing me.

2 boxes containing black and white balls like this:

B1: 2W 1B

B2: 1W 5B

1 ball is moved from B1 to B2, then randomly 1W is drawn from B2.

What is the probability that 1B is moved from B1 to B2.

Answer from the book is 1/5.

Comment: [Bayes' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem).  First, assign names to various events in a convenient manner.  You should have an event describing that you moved a white ball from B1 to B2 versus a black ball.  You should then have an event describing that you picked a white ball from B2.  You should know how to calculate the probability that you selected a white ball from B2 given that a white ball was moved from B1 to B2 earlier.  Similarly, you should know how to calculate the probability you selected a white ball from B2 given that a black ball was moved earlier.

Comment: Thanks for the response, those are very good instructions. I am a beginner and i guess i just need more solved examples to get a feeling for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first consider the case that a white ball was moved.

The probability of the white ball being moved is $\frac23$, and the probability of a white ball being chosen after being moved is $\frac27$. So, the total probability is $\frac4{21}$.

Next, consider the case that a black ball was moved.

The probability of the black ball being moved is $\frac13$, and the probability of a white ball being chosen after the black ball was moved is $\frac17$. So, the total probability is $\frac1{21}$.

Hence, the probability of the black ball being moved is the probability of the black ball being moved and being selected divided by the sum of the probabilities for both colored balls, i.e.,$$\frac{\frac1{21}}{\frac4{21}+\frac1{21}}=\color{red}{\frac15}$$

Answer (score 1):

By the Bayes's theorem:
$$\begin{align}P(B_1|W_2)=\frac{P(B_1\cap W_2)}{P(W_2)}&=\frac{P(B_1)\cdot P(W_2|B_1)}{P(W_1)\cdot P(W_2|W_1)+P(B_1)\cdot P(W_2|B_1)}=\\
&=\frac{\frac13\cdot \frac17}{\frac23\cdot \frac27+\frac13 \cdot \frac17}=\frac15.\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks. Your answer together with Rushabhs explanation is doing the thing.

Comment: Welcome. Just note that the subscripts $1$ and $2$ indicate the first or second ball, respectively. You can accept the other answer, I am fine. Good luck.

Answer (score -3):

Initially there are 2 W and 1 B ball in Box 1.  The probability of moving a white ball from Box 1 to Box 2 is 2/3 and the probability it as a black ball is 2/3.

Imagine doing this "experiment" 210 times.

(2/3)(210)= 140  times you move a white ball to Box 2. there are now 2 white balls and 5 black balls in Box 2.

Of those 140 times, the second ball drawn was white (2/7)(210)= 60 times and (5/7)(210)= 150 times it was black.

(1/3)(210)= 70 times you move a black ball to Box 2.  there are now one white ball and six black balls in Box 2.

Of those 70 times, the second ball drawn was white (1/7)70= 10 times and (6/7)70= 60 times it was black.

Of the 60+ 10= 70 times the white ball was drawn, 10 of them was where the first ball moved was black.  The probability that a black ball was moved from Box 1 to Box 2, given that the ball drawn from box 2 was white is 10/70= 1/7.

Comment: " the probability it as a black ball is 2/3" What do you mean?

Comment: Also, a lot of incorrect arithmetic, i.e., (2/7)(210) instead of (2/7)(140)

Comment: Rushabh Mehta is right, the answer in the book is 1/5 i just cant do it with the Bayes Theorem

Comment: user247327 thank you for your time and effort in helping me.